Are the results reliable if I use semiconductors as electrodes with long screening layers?
If I have enough computing resources to process very large systems so that I could use semiconductors as electrodes no matter how long the screening layer needed, will the results I get be reliable or physical?
I ask this question because I saw some articles doing like this?

If we insist on using semiconductors as electrodes, I think we can make electrodes highly doped, so that the Fermi level is pushed into conduction band or valence band, and then the Fermi level is well defined.

Yes, and then the electrode is not a semi conductor!
